# What are $C_b^2 (\mathbb R)$ and $C^{2,1} (\mathbb R × \mathbb R^+ )$?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

From a [note](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/lec_diff_proc.pdf), for a diffusion process with its transition probability $P(, t|x, s)$,

> Theorem 1. (Kolmogorov) Let $f (x) ∈ C_b (\mathbb R)$ and assume that
>   $$
> u(x, s) := ∫ f (y)P (dy, t|x, s) ∈ C_b^2 (\mathbb R).
> $$
>   Assume furthermore that the functions $a(x, s), b(x, s)$ are
>   continuous in both $x$ and $s$. Then $u(x, s) ∈ C^{2,1} (\mathbb R × \mathbb R^+ )$

I know $C_b (\mathbb R)$ represents the set of continuous and bounded functions defined on $\mathbb R$.
I was wondering what $C_b^2 (\mathbb R)$ and $C^{2,1} (\mathbb R × \mathbb R^+ )$ represent?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I'm not sure about $C^2_b$, but $C^{2,1}$ means that it's $C^2$ in the first variable and $C^1$ in the second.

Comment: What are the functions $a$ and $b$ for?

Comment: @JulianWergieluk: Drift and diffusion.

Answer (score 0):

In the book of "Hybrid switching diffusions" by G. George Yin and Chao Zhu, $C_b^k(\mathbb{R})$ is used to denote the space of real-valued functions with bounded and continuous partial derivatives up to the order $k$. It seems to be fitting here also.